# Local Extreme of the function with end point a and b

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove whether the  following statement is true or false: 
Consider a differentiable function f on a finite closed interval [a, b]. The endpoints a and b are local extrema of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Consider for instance $$f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

(and $f(0)=0$) on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Graph :

[image]

Comment: @CaveJohnson Of course you right, thank you. I edited.